# Font warnings with bmcart

Tags: fonts

This MWE triggers font warnings that I am pretty certain did not occur in January:

```
\documentclass{bmcart}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\dochead{Document}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

I haven't changed `bmcart.cls` since then (versioned `2014/01/24`), so I assume that this is due to changes in other packages or LaTeX binaries (I am using an up-to-date MiKTeX on Windows 10):

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
 ("C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii"

...

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/bx/n' in size <13> not available
(Font)              size <12> substituted on input line 4.

...

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/it' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/sl' tried instead on input line 6.

...

LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 1.0pt have occurred.
```

What can/should I do better/differently?

(Upon visual comparison, I do not see a difference between the old and new documents. Is this maybe only about warnings that were suppressed earlier?)

Comment: bmcart is not in texlive and I don't see it on ctan?  adding `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` will get rid of the size one,  I think the sans serif italic-> slanted substitution is avoidable

Comment: Good point! I did have a hard time finding an official source for `bmcart.cls`, http://media.biomedcentral.com/content/production/bmc_article-tex.zip looks like an official, though deep, link. `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` indeed fixes most of the warnings in my complete document. The only ones remaining so far are `OT1/cmss/m/it` vs. `.../sl` (which I thought I could avoid by using `\textsl` instead of `\textit`) and `OMS/cmss/m/n` vs. `.../cmsy/...` - I'll experiment further with these guys.

Comment: `\usepackage{textcomp}` got rid of the remaining warnings.

Comment: that's weird, textcomp shouldn't change OMS/cmss

Comment: @DavidCarlisle maybe that's due to the copyright symbol? This is my MWE for this instance of the warnings that `textcomp` fixes: `\documentclass{bmcart}\begin{document}\begin{figure}\caption{©}\end{figure}\end{document}`